# Como se pronuncia «Gulbenkian»: «Gulbênquiã», «Gulbênquian» ou «Gulbenquiã»?

Tags: pronúncia

A [Fundação Calouste Gulbenkian](https://gulbenkian.pt/) é um mega instituição cultural em Portugal. Eu devia saber como pronunciar o nome deles, porque comecei as minha leituras com livros da biblioteca itinerante deles, e mais tarde fui bolseiro deles. 
Creio que sempre pronunciei ‘Gulbênkian’ ou ‘Gulbênkiã’ (tónica no *ben*), conforme a disposição e velocidade do discurso. Mas hoje vinha eu a ouvir [Antena 2](http://www.rtp.pt/antena2/), e o locutor pronunciou várias vezes ‘Gulbenkiã’ (tónica no *ã*).

Qual é ou quais são as pronúncias correntes? Havendo mais do que uma, haverá uma preferível?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tenho uma resposta definitiva, mas sendo o Sr Calouste Gulbenkian de origem Arménia, eu diria que a forma mais correcta de pronunciar o seu nome seria na sua língua original o Arménio.

[Segundo a Wikipédia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calouste_Gulbenkian) penso que seria '*Gulbênkian*' com tónica no *E* (é como geralmente pronuncio também).

Gostaria de ouvir um nativo Arménio a pronuncia-lo, mas uma vez que não temos nenhum disponível nem conheço nenhum que pudesse ajuda, o mais próximo que me lembrei de arranjar foi o auxiliar de pronúncia áudio do Google Translator. Bem sei que tem o valor que tem, mas sempre dá uma ajuda. (Carregar nos ícones do altifalante na parte inferior das caixas de texto)

Em [Arménio](https://translate.google.com/#hy/pt/Gulbenkian) parece ser uma voz sintetizada de baixa qualidade, mas tanto a versão [Inglesa](https://translate.google.com/#en/pt/Gulbenkian) como a [Portuguesa](https://translate.google.com/#pt/en/Gulbenkian) parecem confirmar a mesma pronúncia.

Calculo que dado o enraizamento histórico da fundação e do nome na cultura Portuguesa, alguns 'aportuguesamentos' do nome seriam aceitável.

Comment: Todo nome em outra língua se adapta. Nunca se deve mudar a pronuncia para a língua original....A tónica cai no BEN em português.

Comment: O pessoal na Gulbenkian é capaz de ter uma opinião, talvez...

Answer (score 0):

A única pronúncia certa é "gulbenkiã". Por um lado, "devemos respeitar a grafia dos estrangeirismos, bem como a sua pronúncia" (Ciberdúvidas). Em arménio (origem deste antropónimo), pronuncia-se “gulbenkiã”, o que pude confirmar na Fundação Calouste Gulbenkian, onde sou voluntário na área da educação.
Explicação mais desenvolvida em http://portuguesemforma.blogspot.pt/2016/03/diz-se-gulbenkian-ou-gulbenkia.html

Comment: Bem vindo ao site! Tente fazer uma resposta mais completa, porque respostas baseadas em links, os mesmos podem desaparecer e a resposta ficará sem o mínimo de credibilidade. Alguma coisa disponha